# Android and Google Maps API - Icons

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to place markers on the map.
I want to use the standard Google Maps icons for markers.
how do I use them? I don't want to create my own icons.
I'm developing for Android.

in the documentation they tell me to create a class that overrides ItemizedOverlay but in the constructor I'm asked to provide a drawable object.

how do I point to the standard Google Maps ones?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sample [project](http://github.com/ushahidi/Ushahidi_Android/tree/40652a2af85b08aea2ce33c8337168b84344dfb2) helps you.

how to add a itemizedOverlay and when you click on it. it will show an balloon to display what you need..

Answer (score 0):

Those icons are not available from the Google Maps add-on for Android -- or, at least, they are not documented. Perhaps there is a way you can obtain them for legal download through Google Maps for the Web.

Comment: isn't it weird that those are available outside of Android (regular 
use of Google API) but not from the Google-owned Android platform?

Comment: I do not know if add-ons can easily publish resources. I do not know how much engineering time was devoted to the add-on. I do not know what priority Google would place on that development work versus other features. I do not know if Google considers it some sort of branding issue. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be found here: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/